# Git is ignoring yml file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am facing with a strange issue. 
I have private git repo. 
In that if I add a new .yml file then git is ignoring that file but If I add any other file then it's recognising it.

There is no .gitignore file in the repo.

One of my colleague tried to add .yml file in that repo and he is able to do it.

Therefore issue is specific to my system. I could not think anything other than a .gitignore file will do it. ( I even deleted the repo and clone it again but no luck)

Can someone please share some guidance  about this bizzard issue. Where to look at it / what to look at etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
git check-ignore -v file.yml
```

to find out if there is an ignore pattern that ignores the file and from what file the pattern comes. It could be `.git/info/exclude` or global .gitignore.

Comment: That was it. It was added to the  in global gitignore file and it check-ignore -v a.yml, helped me in finding that . Extremely thanks